Unknown 958Hz peak in amplifier/ADC with any input (shorted, opened, signal generator, real signal)
Update 2: I disconnected the ground between channel 1-4 from channel 5-16 and the 958Hz peak disappears. It could be crosstalk but i wonder why crosstalk can produce 958Hz noise.
Update: Using the g.USBamp demo didnt produce the unknown 958Hz peak at the FFT (that BCI2000 software does). See below. Instead there is shift upward in the frequencies.
In both tests. I shorted the differential inputs of channel 1 (In+, In-, ground). I set sampling to 4800Hz, 0.5Hz High Pass and 1000Hz Low Pass using 8th order Butterworth filter and 58-62Hz Notch filter.
Here is the signal and FFT of the g.USBamp.


Why do the lower frequencies shift up? Do you call it baseline shift?
Here is the FFT from the output of the BCI2000 software. All settings the same. Including taken in same sitting and both within 10 minutes.

Why is there no shift of any kind in the BCI2000 output? Instead there is a 958Hz peak that is not seen using the g.USBamp software? What is the cause of the strange 958Hz peak?
Which FFT is the correct one (the one from g.USBamp software shown in the first figure or the BCI2000 software)?
Original question;
I have this second hand g.USBamp 16 channel bioamplifier. There is unknown peak at 958Hz when FFT (both in Sigview and Matlab) when the bandwidth is set to low pass of 1000Hz (or even 2000Hz) with 4800Hz ADC sampling. The 958Hz peak is the same whether the input is shorted, opened, with signal generator input, real bio-signal, etc., with battery only or using AC adaptor. Does anyone any idea where the 958Hz noise could be coming from inside the circuit? Have you encountered anything like it?  Does it occur in the amplifier or ADC? The specs of the g.USBamp is also shown.
The following signal is 9600Hz sampling without any passband nor notch filter, FFT at Matlab. It forms  harmonics or multiple of 958Hz (except the peak near 1400Hz). All 3 inputs shorted (in+,in-, ground). Both 5V USB powerbank and AC adaptor shows same peak at 958Hz and harmonics.

The following signal is 4800Hz sampling (2400Hz sampling  shows same peak) with 5Hz to 1000Hz bandpass and notch filter, Sigview display (Both Sigview and Mathlab used the same data from BCI2000 software). All 3 inputs shorted (in+,in-, ground). Both 5V USB powerbank and AC adaptor shows same peak at 958Hz and harmonics.

https://www.gtec.at/product/gusbamp-research/


Did you try to change the sampling rate by, say, 10%?

240MHz is the USB2 HS Nyquist frequency. 960MHz is typical internal frequency of USB PHY. The description does not mention any antialiasing filtering upfront of the amplifiers, and sampling at 2.4Mz could produce any fake frequency, and no digital post-processing will fix this. Try to put some extra grounding on USB cables, or check for parasitic ground loops in power supplies between the device and host PC. With the sensitivity at microvolt level, you can receive anything.

The FFT figure is with the inputs all shorted and using batteries only. Same peak whether batteries or AC adaptor. ill try changing the sampling.

I tried 2400Hz, 9600Hz sampling with and without bandpass filters. Same peak at 958Hz and  harmonics, see edited and add figure.

How do you know this isn't from dithering or jitter?

As I understand the design from scarce description, you didn't change any initial sampling rate, all is done in post-processing. So if the phantom alias gets into the data when sampling 240MHz at 2.4576MHz rate, post processing won't help. ADC itself is not the entire story. Equally (or even more) important is the analog "front end", which is supposed to filter any noise/harmonics above Nyquist frequency. I strongly suspect it is the original design flaw.

The 2400Hz, 4800Hz, 9600Hz and bandpass  are initial sampling rate one adjusted at source itself. It is not post processing of cors where one adjusted in the saved file. It is always running at 2.4576Mhz with 64 X oversampling so they say there is never any aliasing possible.

in addition to above facts, this is where i read it doesnt produce aliasing   https://www.bci2000.org/mediawiki/index.php/User_Reference:gUSBampADC  "FilterEnabled
Choose 1 if you want a pass band filter, and 0 if you don't. The gUSBamp is a DC amplifier and thus you most likely will want a pass band filter. Please note that, because the g.USBamp internally has a 5kHz antialiasing filter and always samples with 38.4kHz, you DO NOT need to enable any filter if you do not want. You will never experience aliasing."
What does it mean you will never experience aliasing? pls write Answer

"they say there is never any aliasing possible" - I always new that medical doctors are not on very good terms with Electrical Engineering. Even if you have a truly analog antialiasing filter, there are internal wires that go to ADC inputs. And you have a digital processor inside, with USB interface running and likely emitting a lot. With 87nV sensitivity the grounding/shielding/double-shielding should be done very-very carefully. Again, IMPO, the device has some INTERNAL coupling to high-frequency lines (or grounds).  Goofy shape of the device is an indicator of a goofy design, sorry.

the g.USBamp costs about $17500. The most expensive bioamplifier in existence. It is used by major R&D research centers worldwide including multimillion dollar labs. If the analog anti aliasing (or low pass) filter is 5kHz. And your signal is 1000Hz. So without hardware 1000Hz low pass filter. Signal above 1000Hz can still pass thru causing aliasing? The aliasing frequency is 0 to 2400Hz for a 4800Hz sampling rate? I wonder why a $17500 allows aliasing unless they fix it somehow?

I reflect more careuflly how the world's most expensive bioamplifier (again $17500) plus $5k software can't even handle aliasing. Then I read it always samples at 38.4kHz. This means when you do sampling of 4800Hz, it is just like post processing but the real sampling is 38.4kHz so the Nyquist frequency is always 19.2kHz. So with its  5kHz hardware low pass filter. No signal can enter and make it above 19.2kHz and cause aliasing, right? Let's be clear at least this part so we can attribute the noises to grounding, USB, etc. and not to aliasing.

I can't be 100% sure if this is the source in your case, but many USB devices have a problem that causes disturbance around 1000 Hz.
The USB data packets are generally transferred every 1ms so either the data transmission itself or just the increased power consumption to transfer the data may lead to the 1000 Hz disturbance coupling inside a device, maybe through power supplies.
Try it with different PCs to see if the USB polling rate of the specific USB host controller has any effect, or different ports like USB2 and USB3 ports on same PC, etc.
It could also have suffered some damage like a drop or ESD, or have a manufacturing defect or some broken component that now appears as near 1000 Hz frequency everywhere.

I'm using the Microsoft Surface 2017 (with battery only) with only one usb port. Is there a way to add another USB port using the same port? I tried a 4 way USB splitter. same result. So maybe another brand of USB port that plugs into existing port?

@Jtl Using the same port on same computer does not change anything. That is why I said to try on another computer, to rule out that it's not the computer that is causing the ripple on power supply. Also the device you call a "USB splitter" is not a splitter, it is a "USB hub".

Ok, but it would take me time for to use borrow another computer as people don't like to lend computers esp if there are private files. However I have another bio-amplifier, a pure analog one that doesn't have any built in ADC. Is it possible some amplifiers are sensitive to the 1kHz noise while some don't? Here is another amplifier, the BMA-200 which doesn't show any noise at 1kHz. https://a4.pbase.com/o12/95/7576595/1/174505236.5uEjytCl.sigviewoutput2.JPG

@Jtl It is a completely different device so it won't have the same problem as the first device. If the first device is broken or the cause of the noise is because it is connected to PC via USB, then the other device can't have the same problem if it does not connect to PC via USB.

The BMA-200 is connected to the world 2nd best ADC, the E1DA Cosmos ADC wit the follwng most quiet noise profile. You can't see any peak at 1khz. https://a4.pbase.com/o12/95/7576595/1/174518738.iUe9W6r0.e1dacosmosadcnoisefloor.JPG  Also I used the E1da to measure the noise of the BMA-200 and no 1kHz peak. https://a4.pbase.com/o12/95/7576595/1/174518739.geDzv9rI.tiedupinputs1000Hzbandwidthbma.jpg  Even with these. It doesn't eliminate the USB? like perhaps the g.USBamp draws more power from USB? Bec it would take me big effort to convince others to install unknown software is their pc to test
